# Material UI Select in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, material-ui

I have created a dropdown menu using Material UI select. It says "Search By". When we click it, it gives us a list. When I select one of the options, I want to store the option and change the "Search By" to the option selected.

```
export default function UserSearchPage(){
  const [criteria, setCriteria] = useState('');
  const [searchItem, setSearchItem] = useState('');
  return (
    <div>
      <div className='main-content'>
        <Select 
          value = {criteria}
          onChange={
            value => { setCriteria(value);}
          }
          displayEmpty
        >
          <MenuItem disabled value="">
            <em>Search By</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={1}>First Name</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={2}>Last Name</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={3}>Phone Number</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={4}>Email</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </div>
    )
    </div>
  );
}
```

Currently, the onChange gives me this error on value:

```
Argument of type 'ChangeEvent<{ name?: string | undefined; value: unknown; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<string>'.
  Type 'ChangeEvent<{ name?: string | undefined; value: unknown; }>' is not assignable to type '(prevState: string) => string'.
```

and if I use this:

```
onChange={event => setCriteria(event.target.value)}
```

I get:

```
Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<string>'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '(prevState: string) => string'.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to assert the `unknown` typed values before using them. If you're sure that the values from `onChange` events will always be strings, then you can do `onChange={event => setCriteria(event.target.value as string)}` and the compiler should no longer complain.

Comment: This works but I am a bit confused. I am using this on my search bar on the same page and it works ```onChange={value => {
          setSearchItem(value);}}```so how come the same pattern doesn't work for the select?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean your `TextInput`'s `onChange` here. The type definitions for `TextInput`'s `onChange` and `Select`'s `onChange` are not the same. Material UI developers decided to make the `value` type `unknown` for some (I'm sure justified) reason, so you have to do the assertion on that.

Comment: Nope, I meant onChange() for Material UI's SearchBar but yeah the explanation makes sense

Comment: @giotskhada Thank you for your answer. Do you have a recommendation how one could achieve this when using union types (e.g. string | number)?

Answer (score 1):

define a type to your event argument. So it would be

```
onChange={event:React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }> => setCriteria(event.target.value)}
```

Comment: I get this error on onChange: ```No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: SelectProps, context?: any): ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | Component<...> | null', gave the following error.```

Comment: ```Cannot find name 'value'.```

Comment: Maybe you could try here after changing .js files to .tsx https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-payne-frsnt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: if you have strict lint validation this will fail. first answer is the safe way to do that.